# 'filt.dynamic' does not contain a definition for 'name2' and no extension method 'name2'

Tags: c#, html

Hi 
I got this error in c#..since am using the html controls and their id is name 2 it is not recognized in c#..how can i solve this?

string a=project.value;
string b=name2.value;

i used this in c# to store into the database.name2 is the id of textbox created using html..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"id of textbox created using html"
```

I am guessing you've missed out the `runat="server"` from your controls definition.

That is, if it's even an ASP .Net control. Are you defining it as an HTML textbox, or an ASP .net textbox?

Should be: `<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="name2" />`, or similar.

Comment: hi this works great..i had small clarification..i included runat=server in html code as                                    '<SELECT id ="project" name="Project" runat ="server">
                    
 <OPTION value="proj 1">proj 1</OPTION>' but in cshapr while accessing is there any possibility to get without giving the values.. i used '"insert into pro(project)values('"+this.project .Value+ "')"' ..can i use something like this.project.selecteditem